# my items are not clickable while using tabbed fragments

Tags: android

I know the question sounds like it has been answered but in truth i have spent over 4 hours on  with no answer 
everything doesn't seem to work

this is the part of concern any help would be greatly apreciated

```
public class Teams extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<TeamModel> teamModelArrayList;
    TeamsAdapter teamsAdapter;
    View v;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        teamModelArrayList = new ArrayList<TeamModel>();
        teamModelArrayList.add(new TeamModel("whats up people am afraid of ants dont laugh", "class 0f 2010"));



     teamsAdapter = new TeamsAdapter(getActivity(), teamModelArrayList);
            v=getView();
            ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.teamlist);

           listView.setAdapter(teamsAdapter);
           listView.setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), android.R.color.darker_gray));
          listView.setDividerHeight(6);

           listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    launchTeamDetailActivity(position);
                  Log.e("Click", "Click");

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_teams, container, false);




            return rootView;
        }

        public void launchTeamDetailActivity(int position){

            TeamModel teamModel=(TeamModel) teamsAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(), TeamDetailActivity.class );
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.TEAM_NAME,teamModel.getTeamName());
            i.putExtra(MainActivity.CONVERSATION,teamModel.getChatMessage());

            startActivity(i);
    //



        }
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/TeamDisplayPic"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="team tittle"
            android:id="@+id/teamTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/TeamDisplayPic"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/conversationSnippet"
            android:layout_below="@id/teamTitle"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="so this is how it will look like interesting yow awsome stuff"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/TeamDisplayPic"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: THIS IS THE LISTVIEW IN USE <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/teamlist">

</ListView>      AND THE

Comment: Can you show all fragment, from your code it is not clear where adapter and listView initialized

Comment: @Vigen there you go..any suggestions?

Comment: move content of onActivityResult to onCreateView and instead of getView() use rootView

Comment: @Vigen thats what i started out with i thought you would say that it still doesnt work..when i click on the items it does not log anything

Comment: what is content of the "R.layout.list_of_teams"? RelativeLayout under the fragment?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/teamlist">

</ListView>

Comment: adding descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" has worked for me thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your item layout for the `ListView` :

```
<RelativeLayout ...android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"......
```

Comment: do you mean like in the row layout?

Comment: Yes, in the row layout